# ValueError: while trying to use the crispy forms

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I am trying to make use of the crispy forms to display the form for inserting the data. I have a model as:

```
class Athlete(models.Model):
    athlete_name=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    GENDER_CHOICES=(
        ('M','Male'),
        ('F','Female'),
        ('O','Others')
    )
    gender=models.CharField(choices=GENDER_CHOICES,max_length=100)
    age=models.IntegerField()
    athlete_category=models.ForeignKey(Category,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image=models.FileField(upload_to='static/athlete_img', null=True)
    COUNTRY_CHOICES=(
        ('np','nepal'),
        ('in','india'),
        ('uk','united kingdom'),
        ('sp','spain'),
        ('ch','china')
    )
    medals=models.IntegerField
    country=models.CharField(choices=COUNTRY_CHOICES,max_length=100)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.athlete_name
```

In the forms.py...I have modelform as:

```
class AthleteForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model:Athlete
    fields='__all__'
```

In my views.py I have the following function:

```
def add_athlete(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AthleteForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.add_message(request, messages.SUCCESS,
                                 'Athlete added sucessfully')
            return redirect('/admin/athletes')
        else:
            messages.add_message(request, messages.ERROR,
                                 'Enter the appropriate values')
            return render(request, 'forgame/addathletes.html', {
                'form': form
            })
    context = {
        'form': AthleteForm
    }
    return render(request, 'forgame/addathletes.html', context)
```

Inside my templates/forgame I have created addathletes.html

```
{% extends 'layouts.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block title %}
<title>Game Category</title>
{%endblock%}

{% block main_content %}
<div class="container-fluid mt-4">
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <h2>Add Categories Here!</h2>
            {% for msg in messages %}
            {% if msg.level == DEFAULT_MESSAGE_LEVELS.SUCCESS %}
            <div class="alert alert-success">
                {{msg}}
            </div>
            {%endif%}

            {% if msg.level == DEFAULT_MESSAGE_LEVELS.ERROR %}
            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                {{msg}}
            </div>
            {%endif%}
            {%endfor%}

            <form action="" method="post" class="shadow-lg p-3">
                {%csrf_token%}
                {{form | crispy}}
                <div class="mt-3">
                    <input type="submit" value="Add Category" class="btn btn-primary">
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

My urls looks fine but I have been getting this error:
[image]

Along with this:

[image]

Comment: You've written `model:Athlete` instead of `model = Athlete`, so as the error said a model class hasn't been specified for the form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be `=` not `:` so:

```py
class AthleteForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
       model = Athlete
       fields='__all__'
```

I'd also recommend you to maintain gaps between template tags like it should be `{% endblock %}` not `{%endblock%}` same goes for every tag.

Comment: My error has been solved. In the same code...In the form, I get an error "Enter the appropriate values " even though I select the image for the athlete.. Needed help since I am a beginner

Comment: @YanjiLama Are you getting this for `image` field which you set `FileField()`?

Comment: It has been solved: I had missed enctype= multipart/form-data in the form tag. Thank you so much